# Cumulative addition/multiplication in NumPy

Tags: python, performance, numpy, recursion, vectorization

Have a relatively simple block of code that loops through two arrays, multiplies, and adds cumulatively:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11])
b = np.array([0.01, 0.2, 0.03, 0.1, 0.1, 0.6, 0.5, 0.9])
c = []
d = 0
for i, val in enumerate(a):
    d += val
    c.append(d)
    d *= b[i]
```

Is there a way to do this without iterating?  I imagine cumsum/cumprod could be used but I'm having trouble figuring out how.  When you break down what's happening step by step, it looks like this:

```
# 0: 0 + a[0]
# 1: ((0 + a[0]) * b[0]) + a[1]
# 2: ((((0 + a[0]) * b[0]) + a[1]) * b[1]) + a[2]
```

Edit for clarification: Am interested in the list (or array) **c**.

Comment: Do you want both `c` and `d` or is the final value `d` sufficient?

Comment: Actually just need c

Comment: Unrelated to the question: more 'Pythonic' in your loop would have been to do `for val, val_b in zip(a, b):` instead of `enumerate()` and then `b[i]`.

Comment: Good point.  I think I was using the index i as a diagnostic.

Comment: Is this part time critical? You can get about 100 times faster if you go via cython. I am not sure if this can be easily vectorized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In each iteration, you have -

```
d[n+1] = d[n] + a[n]
d[n+1] = d[n+1] * b[n]
```

Thus, essentially -

```
d[n+1] = (d[n] + a[n]) * b[n]
```

i.e. -

```
d[n+1] = (d[n]* b[n]) + K[n]   #where `K[n] = a[n] * b[n]`
```

Now, using this formula if you write down the expressions for until `n = 2` cases, you would have -

> d[1] = d[0]*b[0] + K[0]
>
> d[2] = d[0]*b[0]*b[1] + K[0]*b[1] + K[1]
>
> d[3] = d[0]*b[0]*b[1]*b[2] + K[0]*b[1]*b[2] + K[1]*b[2] + K[2]

```
Scalars      :    b[0]*b[1]*b[2]     b[1]*b[2]        b[2]       1 
Coefficients :         d[0]             K[0]          K[1]       K[2]
```

Thus, you would need reversed cumprod of `b`, perform elementwise multiplication with `K` array. Finally, to get `c`, perform `cumsum` and since `c` is stored before scaling down by `b`, so you would need to scale down the `cumsum` version by the reversed cumprod of `b`.

The final implementation would look like this -

```
# Get reversed cumprod of b and pad with `1` at the end
b_rev_cumprod = b[::-1].cumprod()[::-1]
B = np.hstack((b_rev_cumprod,1))

# Get K
K = a*b

# Append with 0 at the start, corresponding starting d
K_ext = np.hstack((0,K))

# Perform elementwsie multiplication and cumsum and scale down for final c
sums = (B*K_ext).cumsum()
c = sums[1:]/b_rev_cumprod
```

**Runtime tests and verify output**

Function definitions -

```
def original_approach(a,b):
    c = []
    d = 0
    for i, val in enumerate(a):
        d = d+val
        c.append(d)
        d = d*b[i]
    return c

def vectorized_approach(a,b): 
    b_rev_cumprod = b[::-1].cumprod()[::-1]
    B = np.hstack((b_rev_cumprod,1))

    K = a*b
    K_ext = np.hstack((0,K))
    sums = (B*K_ext).cumsum()
    return sums[1:]/b_rev_cumprod
```

**Runtimes and verification**

Case #1: OP Sample case

```
In [301]: # Inputs
     ...: a = np.array([1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11])
     ...: b = np.array([0.01, 0.2, 0.03, 0.1, 0.1, 0.6, 0.5, 0.9])
     ...: 

In [302]: original_approach(a,b)
Out[302]: 
[1,
 2.0099999999999998,
 4.4020000000000001,
 6.1320600000000001,
 7.6132059999999999,
 8.7613205999999995,
 14.256792359999999,
 18.128396179999999]

In [303]: vectorized_approach(a,b)
Out[303]: 
array([  1.        ,   2.01      ,   4.402     ,   6.13206   ,
         7.613206  ,   8.7613206 ,  14.25679236,  18.12839618])
```

Case #2: Large input case

```
In [304]: # Inputs
     ...: N = 1000
     ...: a = np.random.randint(0,100000,N)
     ...: b = np.random.rand(N)+0.1
     ...: 

In [305]: np.allclose(original_approach(a,b),vectorized_approach(a,b))
Out[305]: True

In [306]: %timeit original_approach(a,b)
1000 loops, best of 3: 746 µs per loop

In [307]: %timeit vectorized_approach(a,b)
10000 loops, best of 3: 76.9 µs per loop
```

Please be mindful that for extremely huge input array cases if the `b` elements are such small fractions, because of cummulative operations, the initial numbers of `b_rev_cumprod` might come out as `zeros` resulting in `NaNs` in those initial places.

Comment: Wow, this works great.  Is there any way to return the full list c generated by the original approach?

Comment: @triphook Yes there is! Updated.

Comment: Are there any alternatives to this that can deal with the problem with small fractions? I have a sequence of a few hundred < 1 `b`s and it quickly runs into numerical issues.

Answer (score 3):

Let's see if we can get even faster. I am now leaving the pure python world and show that this purely numeric problems can be optimized even further.

The two players are @Divakar's fast vectorized version:

```
def vectorized_approach(a,b): 
    b_rev_cumprod = b[::-1].cumprod()[::-1]
    B = np.hstack((b_rev_cumprod,1))

    K = a*b
    K_ext = np.hstack((0,K))
    sums = (B*K_ext).cumsum()
    return sums[1:]/b_rev_cumprod
```

and a cython version:

```
%%cython
import numpy as np
def cython_approach(long[:] a, double[:] b):
    cdef double d
    cdef size_t i, n
    n = a.shape[0]
    cdef double[:] c = np.empty(n)

    d = 0
    for i in range(n):
        d += a[i]
        c[i] = d
        d *= b[i]
    return c
```

The cython version is about 5x faster than the vectorized version:

`%timeit vectorized_approach(a,b)` -> `10000 loops, best of 3: 43.4 µs per loop`

`%timeit cython_approach(a,b)` -> `100000 loops, best of 3: 7.7 µs per loop`

Another plus of the cython version is that it is much more readable.

The big downside is that you are leaving pure python and depending on your use case compiling an extension module may not be an option for you.

Comment: Very interesting.  I don't have any experience with cython but this definitely seems like a good option.

Answer (score 2):

This here works for me and is vectorized

```
b_mat = np.tile(b,(b.size,1)).T
b_mat = np.vstack((np.ones(b.size),b_mat))
np.fill_diagonal(b_mat,1)
b_mat[np.triu_indices(b.size)]=1

b_prod_mat = np.cumprod(b_mat,axis=0)
b_prod_mat[np.triu_indices(b.size)] = 0
np.fill_diagonal(b_prod_mat,1)

c = np.dot(b_prod_mat,a)
c

# output
array([  1.   ,   2.01 ,   4.402,   6.132,   7.613,   8.761,  14.257,
        18.128,  16.316])
```

I agree it is not easy to see whats going on. Your array `c` can be written as a matrix-vector multiplication `b_prod_mat * a` where `a` is your array and `b_prod_mat` consists of specific products of `b`. All the emphasis is basically to create `b_prod_mat`.

Comment: The time complexity is much worse, though.

Comment: @user2357112 : You mean it is slower?

Comment: Above some input size threshold, definitely. I haven't timed it, so I don't know what the theshold is. Depending on the constant factor, it could be slower for all inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that's better than a for loop but here is a way:

```
a.dot([np.concatenate((np.zeros(i), (1, ), b[i:-1])) for i in range(len(b))])
```

What it does it's create line of a big matrix `A` like this:

```
1 b0 b0b1 b0b1b2 ... b0b1..bn-1
0  1   b1   b1b2 ...   b1..bn-1
0  0    1     b2 ... 
...
0  0    0      0 ...          1
```

Then you simply multiply the vector `a` with the matrix `A` and you get your expected result.

Comment: The time complexity sucks, and you've still even got a list comprehension in there. The manual loop is probably better.